# How to visualize/interpret text prediction model results?

Tags: prediction, long-short-term-memory, performance, graphs

I am using LSTM model to predict the next xml markup from an input seed.
I have trained my model on 1500 xml files. Each xml file is generated randomly. I am wondering if there is a way to visualize the predicted results in a form of a graph or maybe is it meaningful to do so ?
Since we can do the visualization of classification results, for example in this
[link](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15271/visualizing-results-of-a-classification-problem-excluding-confusion-matrices)

I have done some research on Internet, I have found that there is the confidence measure that can be useful for text prediction task.

I am a bit confused what to do with the text results that I got.